# Display a value of an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm trying to get a specific value from a mysql_fletch_assoc array. I explain. Here is the database. Table: **config** with 2 fields: **setting** and **value**.

```
SETTING | VALUE
width | 100    
height | 50
```

And this is the query:

```
$result = (mysql_query("SELECT setting, value FROM config"));
while($setting = mysql_Fetch_assoc($result)){


    echo $setting['value'];
    echo "<br>";
```

Now i can see the entire array. I want to display every element individually. I tryed with $setting['value']['0'], $setting['value']['width'] with no success.

Edit: basically i want to do something like this:

```
echo $setting['value']['width'] gives -> 100 
echo $setting['value']['height'] gives -> 50
```

I hope that now it's more clear

Comment: Do `var_dump($setting)` to see what's in the array. Is it maybe `$setting['VALUE']`?

Comment: Config and values are what? Table names or table fields? Could you better show the table?

Comment: I don't care what the tutorial site told you, don't use the `mysql` extension. **Ever**. Use `PDO` or `mysqli`. Please reference: http://marc.info/?l=php-internals&m=131031747409271&w=2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, may be there is a typo error `mysql_Fetch_assoc`, fix this to `mysql_fetch_assoc`.

And In order to receive the values on your pattern, do the following

```
$setting = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     $setting['value'][$row['setting']] = $row['value'];
}
```

Now, you can implement them as you want

```
echo $setting['value']['width']; // will give -> 100 
echo $setting['value']['height']; // will give -> 50
```

Comment: I wish me to use font-size=10 to say a BIG THANK YOU! Your code is perfect!

Answer (score 0):

array indices are integers, not strings:

```
$setting['value'][0]
```

Comment: Yep, i also tryed with [0] but with this i get the first char of every record of the array (and i don't get why).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to do something like this:

```
$result = (mysql_query("SELECT setting, value FROM config"));
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo $row['setting'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $row['value'];
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: No. Take a look at the db example i posted above. I just want to get 100 and 50 in two separate variables let's say: $row['setting']['width'] = 100 and $row['setting']['height'] = 50

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with "every element"?
In the while loop $setting contains one returned row:

First loop:

```
$setting = array('config' => 'width', 'value' => 100);
```

Second loop:

```
$setting = array('config' => 'height', 'value' => 50);
```

(nb: mysql_fetch_assoc should be better written with a small f)

Answer (score 0):

Well, considering what Stark just pointed out, I'd suggest you check your table structure. You could have a table structure like this

```
Width | Height
200   |  150
```

So you could always retrieve both with a single query. I'm guessing some sort of ID for the object with these properties, and I don't think in this case it would make a lot of sense to have the properties in different rows on the database.